# Different O/P for same multiprocessing code

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

my code :
running it in repl.it IDE

```
from multiprocessing import Queue

colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'black']
cnt = 1
# instantiating a queue object
queue = Queue()
print('pushing items to queue:')
for color in colors:
    print('item no: ', cnt, ' ', color)
    queue.put(color)
    cnt += 1

print('\npopping items from queue:')
cnt = 1
while not queue.empty():
    print('item no: ', cnt, ' ', queue.get())
    cnt += 1
```

but each time i run it, o/p coming different each time, why is it?

1 -

```
 pushing items to queue:
item no:  1   red
item no:  2   green
item no:  3   blue
item no:  4   black

popping items from queue:
item no:  1   red
item no:  2   green
item no:  3   blue
item no:  4   black
```

2- This time it doesnt show the get o/p

```
pushing items to queue:
item no:  1   red
item no:  2   green
item no:  3   blue
item no:  4   black

popping items from queue:
```

3- This time only 2 o/p of get() part

```
pushing items to queue:
item no:  1   red
item no:  2   green
item no:  3   blue
item no:  4   black

popping items from queue:
item no:  1   red
item no:  2   green
```

Why such happening! Is this to do with some hidden multiprocessing stuff which i dont know?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Queue` is implemented by using a *thread*. which means that each time an item is `put` the thread needs to **pick it up** in some-cases such as your script, the **main thread** is faster and not all items are getting picked up.

If you would have put a small delay (`time.sleep(0.5 # for example`.) you will see it acting normally again.